# Lectura de ficheros en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase Store con un método para leer usuarios de un fichero:

```
 void Store::leerUsuarios(const string &nombreFichero){
 ifstream fichero;
 fichero.open(nombreFichero);
 if (fichero.is_open()) {
    string nom, mail, contrasenya;

    while (!fichero.eof()) {
        fichero >> nombre;
        fichero >> mail;
        fichero >> contrasenya;
    
        usuarios[m_numUsuarios].setUsuarios(nombre, mail, contrasenya);
        m_numUsuarios++;
         }
    fichero.close();
     }
 }
```

Entonces, tengo un fichero .txt con esto:

```
USUARIO_NOM_1 USUARIO_MAIL_1 USUARIO_CONTRASENYA_1 USUARIO_NOM_2 USUARIO_MAIL_2 USUARIO_CONTRASENYA_2 USUARIO_NOM_3 USUARIO_MAIL_3 USUARIO_CONTRASENYA_3 USUARIO_NOM_4 USUARIO_MAIL_4 USUARIO_CONTRASENYA_4
```

El problema es que cuando lo leo, al acabar de leer el usuario 4, vuelve a entrar en el `while(!fichero.eof())`, no debería salir ya que ha acabado de leerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay un matiz que cabe destacar de [`std::ifstream::eof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof), esta función sólo devolverá *verdadero* **después** de haber leído la marca de final de archivo pero no indica que la **siguiente** lectura vaya a ser el final de archivo.

Por eso, después de leer el usuario 4 vuelve a entrar en el bucle, porque en ese momento intenta leer contenido del archivo y no puede, sólo entonces considera que ha llegado al final de archivo y en la siguiente vuelta la llamada a `std::ifstream::eof` devuelve *verdadero*.

Una posible solución es la que propone [Triztian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/167991/2742), otra solución podría ser aprovechar que `std::ifstream` es [convertible a booleano](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) y que será convertido a *falso* tras una lectura fallida para escribir algo así:

```
while ((fichero >> nombre) && (fichero >> mail) && (fichero >> contrasenya)) {
    usuarios[m_numUsuarios].setUsuarios(nombre, mail, contrasenya);
    m_numUsuarios++;
}
```

Si la lectura `fichero >> nombre` falla por falta de datos, dejando el `ifstream` en un estado incorrecto, la conversión a booleano devolverá *falso* y además de que el resto de lecturas no se realizarán, no se entrará en el bucle.

Answer (score 3):

intenta con esto, hace use de `sstream` (streams de strings) para procesar cada linea:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

struct usuario {
    std::string nombre;
    std::string mail;
    std::string password;
};

// sobrecargar el operador "<" para que el struct se 
// pueda utilizar en el conjunto `std::set<usuario>`
inline bool operator<(const usuario& x, const usuario& y) {
    return x.mail < y.mail && x.nombre < y.nombre;
}

// declarar el prototipo de la funcion
std::set<usuario> leerFichero(const std::string&);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: file path missing" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::set<usuario> usuarios = leerFichero(std::string(argv[1]));

    std::cout << "Numero Usuarios: " << usuarios.size() << std::endl;

    for (auto user : usuarios) {
        std::cout << "Nombre: " << user.nombre << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Mail: " << user.mail << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

/**
 * leerFichero recibe la ruta completa de un fichero a leer, cada
 * linea del ficher contiene 3 campos delimitados por espacios, siendo
 * estos `nombre`, `mail` y `contraseña`.
 * Si el fichero no puede ser abierto, regresa un conjunto vacío.
 */
std::set<usuario> leerFichero(const std::string& nombreFichero) {

    std::ifstream fichero;

    fichero.open(nombreFichero);

    std::set<usuario> usuarios;

    if (!fichero.is_open()) {
        return usuarios;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(fichero, line)) {

        // saltarse la linea si esta vacía
        if ( line == "" ) {
            continue;
        }

        std::istringstream linestream(line);

        usuario *user = new usuario();

        linestream >> user->nombre;
        linestream >> user->mail;
        linestream >> user->password;

        usuarios.insert(*user);
    }

    fichero.close();

    return usuarios;
}
```